# Get the position in a Grid from a dynamic object

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

On GridItem object there's a colIndex and on GridRow a rowIndex. But both are declared internal so I do not have acces on that information.

Is there another way to get the position of an object in a grid.

cyrill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the mx_internal namespace to reference these properties. Be careful what you do with them though, as i'm sure adobe put them in the mx_internal namespace for a reason.

How to use mx_internal: http://codeofdoom.com/wordpress/2009/03/12/when-and-how-to-use-mx_internal-in-flex/

Also, I believe Grid is deprecated in recent versions of flex and it's recommended (in flex 3) that you use constraint columns and rows instead.